# Adding a switch to header jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, header, switch-statement

I am trying to add a switch to the header. it is working fine, but the switch is on the next line, i want it on the right of the title

Code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="moreevents">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#defaultclub" data-icon="arrow-l" data-theme="b" onclick="getClubData(curClub)" id="backtoclub">Back</a>
        <h1>All Events</h1>
        <div align="right">
            <select name="switch" id="alleventsswitch" data-role="slider">
            <option value="off">No Past</option>
            <option value="on">Past</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Working Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Y9ntF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/Y9ntF/1/

You need to reduce default `h1` width and margin to give a space for `switch`.

## HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="moreevents">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#defaultclub" data-icon="arrow-l" data-theme="b" onclick="getClubData(curClub)" id="backtoclub">Back</a>
        <h1 id="myTitle">All Events</h1>
        <span id="mySelect">
            <select name="switch" id="alleventsswitch" data-role="slider">
            <option value="off">No Past</option>
            <option value="on">Past</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#myTitle{
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    margin: .6em 0 .8em 40%;
}
#mySelect{
    float:right;
    z-index: 1;
}
```